# how to get emails newer than a specific date and time in gmail API php

Tags: php, email, gmail-api

I would like to know that how can I fetch emails using Gmail API in php which are newer than a date and time. like `2017-10-21 09:00:47`. I've used query param `newer_than` but it didn't work. Then I used `after: 2017-10-21 09:00:47` it also didn't worked. then I done something like this.

```
<?php
$time = strtotime('2017-10-21 09:00:47');
// and passed it in query like this
$query = "after: $time";
?>
```

it now fetches results but it includes the messages which are received at that time. I do not want to include messages of that time. How do I exclude them?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `after`, but convert the date to seconds and use that.

Let's say you wanted messages you got later than `Friday, October 20, 2017 11:59:59 PM`. You would then write `after:1508543999` in your query.

Comment: Bro, doing same thing. It includes all the messages of time `Friday, October 20, 2017 11:59:59 PM` . I want messages after `Friday, October 20, 2017 11:59:59 PM` . messages for that time should not be included.